# How to solve the AWS S3 Object Lambda function invalid token error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I was testing Python [Amazon S3 Object Lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/transforming-objects.html) and it gave an invalid token error when executing time is longer than 60s. The sample code and error messages are attached.

```
import boto3
import json
import struct
from botocore.session import Session
from botocore.config import Config
import time

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print('event', event)
    object_get_context = event["getObjectContext"]
    request_route = object_get_context["outputRoute"]
    request_token = object_get_context["outputToken"]
    s3_url = object_get_context["inputS3Url"]
    
    s = Session()
    s3 = s.create_client('s3', config=Config(connect_timeout=300, read_timeout=300, retries={'max_attempts': 1}))
    
    
    print("start")
    time.sleep(60)
    print("sleep for 60s")
    
    s3.write_get_object_response(
        Body=b"123",
        RequestRoute=request_route,
        RequestToken=request_token)

    return {'status_code': 200}
```

```
[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the WriteGetObjectResponse operation: Invalid token
```

When I changed the sleep time to 50s, it executed successfully. And I've changed the both client side timeout and lambda timeout. I guess there may be some other parameters controlling this but I don't know.

Comment: If this is taking in an s3 presigned url, check the expiration of the token, may need to increase that timeout. The default is 3600 seconds though if not specified https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/presign.html#:~:text=Default%20is%203600%20seconds.

Comment: Why are you sleeping within the Object Lambda function? Your function should retrieve, transform, and write the object content as quickly as possible.

Comment: Yeah, it's just a testing function.

Answer (score 2):

It is a constraint of [AWS S3 Object Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/olap-best-practices.html) (not Lambda itself)

> S3 Object Lambda allows up to 60 seconds to stream a complete response to its caller